# SQL Server Reporting Service programming issue

Tags: sql-server, service, reporting

I understand how to manully connect to a SQL Server data source and input SQL statement to generate/publish a report on the web. My question is, I want end user to input some parameter values, then use such parameter values as SQL statement parameter values (e.g. using end user input time range as SQL statement parameters) -- then generating report based on such parameters dynamically. I am looking for any related samples/documents. Any recommendations?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have parameters set up they will be requested in report manager.

Here is a [tutorial](http://en.csharp-online.net/Building_Reports_in_SQL_Server_2005%E2%80%94Setting_Report_Parameters_with_Stored_Procedures)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for report parameters.

A pretty good tutorial on the subject can be found at
[this site.](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/reporting/report_parameters_p1.aspx)